# Vim inserts invisible strange characters which result in a syntax error

Tags: macos, vim, homebrew, zsh

Occasionally when using vim, invisible characters are inserted which result in a syntax error. When I delete the line and rewrite it it works.

In my case RubyMine also states that an error exists in this line. In basically makes vim a pain because it inserts invisible bugs in my code.

I'm using Mac with zsh as my shell. Furthermore I'm using vim installed using homebrew

Comment: Next time, do a `ga` on the invisible character (or convert into a hexdump via `:%!xxd`), and note down its value. Hopefully, that will give you a clue from where this gets inserted.

Comment: It's unlikely that this is happening randomly. If you can identify what the character being added is, it might help. If you're seeing this after pasting from the clipboard or using the mouse in some way, that might be the reason, but first try to identify both the trigger and the actual character value.

Comment: I Identified the character. It is a '|'. It does not only happen when using vim but also with zsh generally

Comment: Hi guys. today I was developing in scala when this error occured again. It seems to be a null byte (\u00a0) which is inserted into my code. Did anybody experience this aswell ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this problem occurs with anyone else, it was the ALT/OPTION + SPACE key on MacOS that created this problem and not related to vim or zsh at all.

A solution can be found here: https://superuser.com/questions/78245/how-to-disable-the-option-space-key-combination-for-non-breaking-spaces

Comment: thank you, this also happens on Ubuntu when editing latex - a mysterious `$` was inserted

Comment: I had this problem when I used the tab key when editing on Mac OS.